# MySQL Query and DataGridView - Relating data with same ID

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, datagridview

I've got a problem on realting data with the same id's, like, I have a table named: idClients and another table named idAnnouncements, and I have a datagridview on visualstudio, I want to put all the data from idAnnouncements that have the same idClients.

//TABLE ANNOUNCEMENTS

http://prntscr.com/m8u8kc

Translation portuguese to english
(idClientes --> id Clients)
(idAnuncios -->idAnnouncements)

//METHOD TO PUT DATA ON DATAGRID VIEW

```
public void PreencherDataGridView()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        query = " //the query I need";
        ler = ligaBD.ExecutaSelects(query);
        dt.Load(ler);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
        }

        ler.Close();
    }
```

To be more direct, I choose an ID here, and it appears all the info from the clients who have that ID down there: http://prntscr.com/m8ufhe

Comment: Are you getting an exception or you need a sample of SQL query?

Comment: I need only a SQL Query to relate this

Answer (score 0):

This query sample loads all clients and their announcements:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Clients AS c
INNER JOIN Announcements AS a ON a.idClientes = c.idAnuncios;
```

Comment: OK, query is working but I need to realte the fieldText where I put on the IDClient I want to search with the query, I put on the post one more screenshoot for you to see.